# jQuery - Unchecked other checkbox when CHECK ALL is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

**My purpose**

When I click `Check All` in the first column, all check boxes in that column should be checked and the <kbd>Set</kbd> button should show up. While the other check boxes in other column should be unchecked. Besides, when I click `Check All` in the second column, the <kbd>Set</kbd> button in the first column will be hidden and show up in the second column and then uncheck other check boxes.

**HTML CODE :**

```
<div id="allCheckboxes">
<table width="500px">
 <tr>
    <td>Check ALL <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll_1"><div id="setBttn_1" style="display:none;"><input type="button" value="Set"></div></td>
    <td>Check ALL <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll_2"><div id="setBttn_2" style="display:none;"><input type="button" value="Set"></div></td>
    <td>Check ALL <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll_3"><div id="setBttn_3" style="display:none;"><input type="button" value="Set"></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox1" name="Box1" checked value="1" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox2" name="Box2" value="12"/></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox3" name="Box3" value="13"/></td>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox10" name="Box1" checked value="001" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox20" name="Box2" value="182"/></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox30" name="Box3" value="123"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox11" name="Box1" value="333" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox181" name="Box2" value="184442"/></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox101" name="Box3" checked value="1243"/></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
$('#checkAll_1').change(function () {
  $('[name="Box1"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  if($('#checkAll_1').is(':checked')) {
    $('#setBttn_1').show();
  } else {
    $('#setBttn_1').hide();
  }
});
$('#checkAll_2').change(function () {
  $('[name="Box2"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  if($('#checkAll_2').is(':checked')) {
    $('#setBttn_2').show();
  } else {
    $('#setBttn_2').hide();
  }
});
$('#checkAll_3').change(function () {
  $('[name="Box3"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  if($('#checkAll_3').is(':checked')) {
    $('#setBttn_3').show();
  } else {
    $('#setBttn_3').hide();
  }
});
```

The current result is when I click `Check All` in the first column, it won't uncheck other check boxes. When I click `Check All` in the second column, the <kbd>Set</kbd> button in the first column won't hide. Is it possible to go back to the previously checked option(s) just before the current selection if I unclick "Check All"?

**LIVE DEMO :** http://jsfiddle.net/WzuMa/142/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `prop` does not fire change (with good reason, as that could  cause recursive events by default).

You can simply trigger the `change()` event after setting `prop`, but you need to ensure it does not fire recursively (so added a sentinel variable):

```
var processing = false;
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  if (!processing) {
    processing = true;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
    processing = false;
  }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/WzuMa/143/

### Update - Restore previous values on uncheck

```
var processing = false;
var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
$checkboxes.on('change', function() {
  if (!processing) {
    processing = true;
    if (this.checked){
        // Store all answers on a data attribute
        $checkboxes.each(function(){
            $(this).data('lastcheck', $(this).prop('checked'));
        });
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
    }
    else {
            // Restore all the previous checked box states
        $checkboxes.not(this).each(function(){
                $(this).prop('checked', $(this).data('lastcheck')).removeData('lastcheck');
        });
    }
    processing = false;
  }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/WzuMa/144/

*You can tweak this technique to operate on rows instead, for the lower checkboxes but I have to leave something for you to do :)*

Comment: is it possible to return previous attribute or condition if unchecked the "Click All"???

Comment: @user1234: sure but you need to decide what "previous" means for your UI. E.g. Do you want to go back to the previously checked option(s) just before the current selection?

Comment: i want make it go back to previously checked option(s) if unclick "Check All".. how to do it???

Comment: @user1234: You do realise that is non-standard behaviour you are introducing? Not sure your users will be impressed with it flicking back to previous selections when you uncheck a single checkbox. The solution is to store the previous check values, of all checkboxes as a data attribute/value on those controls. You then just revert back to their stored values (except the current one). Example added above.

Answer (score 1):

You you are programmatically setting the `checked` property it doesn't triggers the `change` event handler.

To trigger the event handler, `.trigger(event)` function should be used.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});

$('#checkAll_1').change(function() {
  $('[name="Box1"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).trigger('change');
  if ($('#checkAll_1').is(':checked')) {
    $('#setBttn_1').show();
  } else {
    $('#setBttn_1').hide();
  }
});

$('#checkAll_2').change(function() {
  $('[name="Box2"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).trigger('change');
  if ($('#checkAll_2').is(':checked')) {
    $('#setBttn_2').show();
  } else {
    $('#setBttn_2').hide();
  }
});

$('#checkAll_3').change(function() {
  $('[name="Box3"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).trigger('change');
  if ($('#checkAll_3').is(':checked')) {
    $('#setBttn_3').show();
  } else {
    $('#setBttn_3').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="allCheckboxes">
  <table width="500px">
    <tr>
      <td>Check ALL
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll_1">
        <div id="setBttn_1" style="display:none;">
          <input type="button" value="Set">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Check ALL
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll_2">
        <div id="setBttn_2" style="display:none;">
          <input type="button" value="Set">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Check ALL
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll_3">
        <div id="setBttn_3" style="display:none;">
          <input type="button" value="Set">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox1" name="Box1" checked value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox2" name="Box2" value="12" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox3" name="Box3" value="13" />
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox10" name="Box1" checked value="001" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox20" name="Box2" value="182" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox30" name="Box3" value="123" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox11" name="Box1" value="333" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox181" name="Box2" value="184442" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox101" name="Box3" checked value="1243" />
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
$('#allCheckboxes').find('tr').first().find(':checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    idx = $this.closest('td').index();
  $('div[id^="setBttn"]').hide();
  $this.next('div').toggle(this.checked);
  $('[id^="checkAll"]:checked').not(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);
  $('#allCheckboxes').find('tr').not(':first').each(function() {
    $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked', !$this.prop('checked'));
    $(this).find('td').eq(idx).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', $this.prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="allCheckboxes">
  <table width="500px">
    <tr>
      <td>Check ALL
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll_1">
        <div id="setBttn_1" style="display:none;">
          <input type="button" value="Set">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Check ALL
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll_2">
        <div id="setBttn_2" style="display:none;">
          <input type="button" value="Set">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Check ALL
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll_3">
        <div id="setBttn_3" style="display:none;">
          <input type="button" value="Set">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox1" name="Box1" checked value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox2" name="Box2" value="12" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox3" name="Box3" value="13" />
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox10" name="Box1" checked value="001" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox20" name="Box2" value="182" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox30" name="Box3" value="123" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox11" name="Box1" value="333" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox181" name="Box2" value="184442" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox101" name="Box3" checked value="1243" />
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @user1234 better to use named radios then.

Answer (score 1):

Try below JS for now things are hard-coded but if this solution is as expected as you then I can update it to more dynamics

```js
  

 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  
 });
 
 $('#checkAll_1').change(function () {
   $('[name="Box1"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    $('[name="Box2"],[name="Box3"]').prop('checked', false);
 if($('#checkAll_1').is(':checked')){
   $('#setBttn_1').show();
     $('#setBttn_2,#setBttn_3').hide();
   }else{
   $('#setBttn_1').hide();
  }
    
 });
 
 $('#checkAll_2').change(function () {
  $('[name="Box2"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
      $('[name="Box1"],[name="Box3"]').prop('checked', false);
   if($('#checkAll_2').is(':checked')){
   $('#setBttn_2').show();
      $('#setBttn_1,#setBttn_3').hide();
   }else{
   $('#setBttn_2').hide();
  }
 });
 
 $('#checkAll_3').change(function () {
  $('[name="Box3"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
      $('[name="Box1"],[name="Box2"]').prop('checked', false);
   if($('#checkAll_3').is(':checked')){
   $('#setBttn_3').show();
      $('#setBttn_1,#setBttn_2').hide();
   }else{
   $('#setBttn_3').hide();
  }
 });
```

Comment: how to make it into more dynamic?

Comment: That I need to do more work on this is it ok means functionality is ik for you?

Comment: it work perfect.thank.i would like to ask is it possible to return previous attribute or condition if unchecked the "Click All"???

Comment: Sorry but I am not clear on your point can you please explain me more - is it possible to return previous attribute or condition if unchecked the "Click All"???

Comment: @user1234 try nowe number of lines are now minimum in code. will try to make solution more generic but for now this is only I did.

Comment: It mean when i unclick the "Check All", it return to the previous checked attribute..

Comment: I think this is not possible in this case you need to maintain many things like how many check boxes are check  id of all checkbooks. I think this is not simple solution need to work on this